# Distribute iOS app without human interaction

Tags: ios, applications, development, automation

Is there a way to deploy an iOS app to a device without requiring human interaction.

By 'no human interaction', for instance, consider an automated scenario (in a CI environment) where the server can deploy an app to a device and there is no need to have a person to go to the device in order to open an URL and click 'install'.

Following image shows what I want to avoid.

[image: App deployment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do unattended (or silent) installs from iOS 7 onwards on supervised devices. For iOS 6, the user will see the install/cancel prompt and unattended installs without user intervention is not possible.

From [Apple Launches "Managed Distribution" for App Store Volume Purchase Program (VPP) for Business and Education (Submitted by Aaron Freimark on November 4, 2013 - 11:08pm)](http://www.enterpriseios.com/story/2013/11/04/Apple_Launches_Managed_Distribution_for_App_Store_Volume_Purchase_Program_VPP_for_B):

> Apple tonight updated its app Volume Purchase Program with several long-anticipated and important additions. The updates introduce a new "managed distribution" of apps to iOS 7 devices, allowing assignment and revocation' through Mobile Device Management.
>   ...
>   Assigned apps are **installed automatically** on supervised devices. Unsupervised devices show a prompt to install.

From [iOS 7: What it means for Enterprise, Education, and Government (
By Craig Johnston, Thursday, Sep 19, 2013 a 11:16 am )](http://www.imore.com/ios-7-what-it-means-enterprise-education-and-government)

> With iOS 7 the following has been added:
>   **Silent app installation.** Now via the MDM API, an IT administrator can send an app to the device and have it installed silently in the
>   background. There is no need to ask the user which delays compliance,
>   the app just installs itself. This works both for apps in the iTunes
>   App Store that the company may have purchased a volume license for and
>   apps developed by the company itself for internal use, that are not
>   stored in the iTunes App Store.

Contrast this with what iOS 6 provides (described in the same article), which is (italics mine):

> In iOS 6, through the use of MDM APIs you could:
>   Install Apps via MDM. This feature tells the user that they must install an app. *The user could ignore this message and the
>   administrator will have to decide how to handle this. They could set
>   the MDM system to automatically lock their device out until they
>   install the app. They could keep calling the user asking them to
>   install the app. Either way, the app cannot be installed for the user
>   by the IT team.*

Comment: Can you add any experience you have with this if you've used a specific MDM to deploy? The announcements were kind of like CarPlay where we had to wait for both apple and the MDM providers to connect the dots.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You need to create a profile for said device(s). Profile Manager and Apple Configurator are your friends for such tasks.

Comment: Could you list what version of server app and what version of iOS that you have seen this work on?